# Can the startup script on a Google Compute Engine instance run with command line arguments?

Tags: google-compute-engine

We are creating instances via command line like this:

```
gcloud compute instances create instance-name [--stuff otherstuff] --metadata-from-file startup-script=scriptname.sh
```

Is there any way to specify command line arguments for that startup script? We use an almost identical script for several instances, and it seems like too much duplication.

Comment: Perhaps you could store the variable arguments themselves as metadata and then have the startup script get them from the metadata server at instance creation time. Or simply use some combination of perl/sed etc. at the time you create the instance, feeding in a customized scriptname.sh file with the arguments stored in env variables.

Comment: You're saying I should pass the specific value through the regular metadata and use it in the startup script? Does the shell command I used support both '--metadata' and '--metadata-from-file' arguments at the same time? I don't think it says anything about that, so I guess it would.

Comment: [--metadata KEY=VALUE,[KEY=VALUE,...]]
[--metadata-from-file KEY=LOCAL_FILE_PATH,[KEY=LOCAL_FILE_PATH,...]]

Comment: @snetch Did you find the solution ? If yes, can you post it as answer so that other users with the similar question can refer to it. Thanks

Comment: I did not. The only thing I have going for it is jarmod's comment, and it's not exactly what I was looking for. I guess I'll post that.

Comment: @snetch the best way to achieve your setup is using metadata as mentioned by jarmod. You can use project or instance metadata to store these keys. For more information you can refer to this [link](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/metadata)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like there isn't a way to make scripts use command like arguments inside them, like by using `$1` and `$2` and such in bash.

Other metadata variables can be used to pass the extra information into the script in a similar way, but then the script will have to be crafted specifically to be a Google Compute Engine startup script and always have that specific variable passed to the instance along with it.